# Pandas Dataframe delete row by repitition

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to delete a row in a dataframe that is imported into python by pandas.

if you see the sheet below, the first column has same name multiple times. So the condition is, if the first column value re-appears in a next row, delete that row. If not keep that frame in the dataframe.

[image]

My final output should look like the following: 
[image]

Presently I am doing it by converting each column into a list and deleting them by index values. I am hoping there would be an easy way. Rather than this workaround/

Comment: df.drop_duplicates('col1')

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates([df.columns[0])
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code;

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='columnName', keep=’first’, inplace=true)
```